# Как спрятать блок при скроле?

Tags: javascript, css

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать такую штуку. Есть блок, и я хочу чтобы при скроле вверх/низ он уходил в display:none а если перестал скролить то он появился в display:block. Т.е. чтобы была

```css
#block{
background:red;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="block"></div>
```

, если скролишь то он исчезает(скролишь вверх или же вниз), а если скрола нету то он появляется. Надо с учетом на то что на телефоне так же будет работать.
Спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать через функцию `setTimeout` и `clearTimeout`.
Минус данного метода в том что при каждом скрулле вы обновляете переменную `showBlock`.

```js
let block = document.querySelector('#block');
let showBlock;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  clearTimeout(showBlock);
  block.style.display = 'none';

  showBlock = setTimeout(() => {
    block.style.display = 'block';
  }, 20);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1600px;
}

#block {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 24px;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```